# How to simulate two computers connected with LAN when you have only one computer?

Tags: linux, networking

I wish to test a networking application between two computers connected by LAN. These computers will have different IP addresses.

I have only one computer.

How to simulate two computers connected with LAN and having different IP addresses when I have only one computer?

```
Platform: Linux.
Language: C
```

Comment: Probably use one (or two, if you want to isolate from your host environment) virtual machines. Alternatively, you *might* be able to get away with just using different ports on loopback (or configuring routing such that a private IP is locally routed back to loopback).

Comment: @Bob Could you explain please "how" to use virtual machine such that the physical computer sees the other's IP address?

Comment: What? Set up a virtual machine, set up networking depending which VM software you are using, plenty of guides, etc.. There's a reason I posted that as a comment and not an answer, but even as an answer I'd expect you to be able to search for yourself given a nudge in the right direction, not a step by step guide. A step by step guide to setting up VM networking would likely be closed as a duplicate anyway.

Comment: As what Bob has said, set up a VM (or two). Make sure the VM is set to use Bridged Adapter so they get their own IP address (not simply re-using your current PC connection).

Comment: @Darius VM software often has a host-only/internal (or maybe even NAT) mode which would be good enough for internal testing, as long as you don't need to access it from an external network. But I really don't want to go into specifics, especially without knowing more about his situation or what VM software will be used.

Comment: @Bob I'll be using virtual box software. Nor I did expect people to give step by step instructions. I was expecting "keywords" which I could search in Google to get this setup.

Comment: @AnishaKaul `virtualbox networking` => http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html <= take a look at internal and host only, since you should not need to access it from other computers on the host's physical network.

Comment: @Bob Alright, will study that.

Comment: @Bob One more question: I won't need any extra hardware to make this work? Will I?

Comment: @user462608 No, you won't, though it would help immensely if your CPU had hardware virtualisation support. VM networking is all software. Internet networks are just between VMs, while host-only networks create an additional interface on the host to add it to the network. NAT provides internet access out to the external network, while bridged provides access in and out (you probably won't need that).

Comment: @Bob You have been helpful. Can you put all your comments as an answer so that I can select it?

Comment: (I meant *internal* networks in the previous comment... damn that typo!) @user462608 there is an existing answer suggesting a possibly better virtualisation method. VBox *works*, but under Linux you might find paravirtualisation to be faster (e.g. OpenVZ, LXC, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to give LXC a try. If provides lightweight virtualization (=not much resource usage) and every virtual environment has a separate network stack. You can also access the VE's disk space from the host operating system to compile your applications directly, or even bind mount a directory into them.